# Sharepoint and CDN

Tags: 2007

Has anybody used Content Delivery Network (CDN) with Sharepoint Internet Facing Site (Publishing). If so how to use it

Comment: Please could you expand on this question? Which CDNs are you wanting to use, what are you wanting to use them for. At the moment this question could be replied to with "Yes. You use them as you normally would".

Comment: There are CDN's like Akamai,Cache fly, Limelight which are used for regular websites. Is there any guidelines specific to Sharepoint and CDN's or any referral implementation

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the-box CDN configuration stuff. It's all up to you how you design and create your master pages. It's just like any other web site using CDN.

You need to do custom development if you want to push images from an Asset library or similar and copy those files to the CDN though.